# Detect maximum value in a returned table after executing a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that will return a grid counting records according to the weekday and the hour, the result of that query is:

[image: IMG]

And this is the query that builds that table:

```
DECLARE @p varchar(10)
SET @p = 
(
    SELECT
        [A].[PeriodoAcad] 
    FROM [dbo].[Periodos_Academicos] [A]
    WHERE
        ([A].[Estado] = 'True')
)


;WITH [pivotData] as
(
    SELECT  
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Day],
        DATEPART(HOUR,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Hour],
        [p].[ID] as [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion] [P]
    WHERE [P].[Periodo] = @p
)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            [Day] 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'       
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'        
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'        
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Miércoles'       
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'        
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'        
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sábado' 
        END AS [Dia],
        [0] AS [00:00],
        [1] AS [01:00],
        [2] AS [02:00],
        [3] AS [03:00],
        [4] AS [04:00],
        [5] AS [05:00],
        [6] AS [06:00],
        [7] AS [07:00],
        [8] AS [08:00],
        [9] AS [09:00],
        [10] AS [10:00],
        [11] AS [11:00],
        [12] AS [12:00],
        [13] AS [13:00],
        [14] AS [14:00],
        [15] AS [15:00],
        [16] AS [16:00],
        [17] AS [17:00],
        [18] AS [18:00],
        [19] AS [19:00],
        [20] AS [20:00],
        [21] AS [21:00],
        [22] AS [22:00],
        [23] AS [23:00]
    FROM [pivotData]
        PIVOT
            (
                COUNT([ID]) FOR [Hour] 
                IN 
                (
                    [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
                )
            ) AS [pivoted]
```

I'm trying to set the cell's colour according to its value. So as you can see, the maximum value on that table is 30, that corresponds to Tuesday 16:00. So i need that 30 is the colour at 100%: the minimum value (that is 0) should be 0%, and the value 1 should be 3.33% ( (1/30) * 100). That will give me the colour scale I need.

How can I detect the maximum value in that table?

So far I've been able to try this solution, but its not working:

```
DECLARE @p varchar(10)
SET @p = 
(
    SELECT
        [A].[PeriodoAcad] 
    FROM [dbo].[Periodos_Academicos] [A]
    WHERE
        ([A].[Estado] = 'True')
)

DECLARE @max int 
SET @max =
(
    ;WITH [pivotData] as
    (
        SELECT  
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Day],
            DATEPART(HOUR,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Hour],
            [p].[ID] as [ID]
        FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion] [P]
        WHERE [P].[Periodo] = @p
    )
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                [Day] 
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'       
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'        
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'        
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Miércoles'       
                WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'        
                WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'        
                WHEN 7 THEN 'Sábado' 
            END AS [Dia],
            [0] AS [00:00],
            [1] AS [01:00],
            [2] AS [02:00],
            [3] AS [03:00],
            [4] AS [04:00],
            [5] AS [05:00],
            [6] AS [06:00],
            [7] AS [07:00],
            [8] AS [08:00],
            [9] AS [09:00],
            [10] AS [10:00],
            [11] AS [11:00],
            [12] AS [12:00],
            [13] AS [13:00],
            [14] AS [14:00],
            [15] AS [15:00],
            [16] AS [16:00],
            [17] AS [17:00],
            [18] AS [18:00],
            [19] AS [19:00],
            [20] AS [20:00],
            [21] AS [21:00],
            [22] AS [22:00],
            [23] AS [23:00]
        FROM [pivotData]
            PIVOT
                (
                    COUNT([ID]) FOR [Hour] 
                    IN 
                    (
                        [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
                    )
                ) AS [pivoted]
    )
```

EDIT:

Regarding the colour: I'm rendering this table on a asp:GridView control, so I intend to bring the background color declared on a div. This will be the desired result on the query (only the result):

```
DECLARE @p varchar(10)
SET @p = 
(
    SELECT
        [A].[PeriodoAcad] 
    FROM [dbo].[Periodos_Academicos] [A]
    WHERE
        ([A].[Estado] = 'True')
)


;WITH [pivotData] as
(
    SELECT  
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Day],
        DATEPART(HOUR,[P].[FechaEnv]) as [Hour],
        [p].[ID] as [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion] [P]
    WHERE [P].[Periodo] = @p
)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            [Day] 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'       
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'        
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'        
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Miércoles'       
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'        
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'        
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sábado' 
        END AS [Dia],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [0]) + '</div>' AS [00:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [1]) + '</div>' AS [01:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [2]) + '</div>' AS [02:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [3]) + '</div>' AS [03:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [4]) + '</div>' AS [04:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [5]) + '</div>' AS [05:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [6]) + '</div>' AS [06:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [7]) + '</div>' AS [07:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [8]) + '</div>' AS [08:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [9]) + '</div>' AS [09:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [10]) + '</div>' AS [10:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [11]) + '</div>' AS [11:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [12]) + '</div>' AS [12:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [13]) + '</div>' AS [13:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [14]) + '</div>' AS [14:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [15]) + '</div>' AS [15:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [16]) + '</div>' AS [16:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [17]) + '</div>' AS [17:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [18]) + '</div>' AS [18:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [19]) + '</div>' AS [19:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [20]) + '</div>' AS [20:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [21]) + '</div>' AS [21:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [22]) + '</div>' AS [22:00],
        '<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [23]) + '</div>' AS [23:00]
    FROM [pivotData]
        PIVOT
            (
                COUNT([ID]) FOR [Hour] 
                IN 
                (
                    [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
                )
            ) AS [pivoted]
```

So, the line that states:

```
'<div style="background-color: rgba(120,120,120,1);">' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [23]) + '</div>' AS [23:00]
```

Should dynamically ser the value of alpha rgba(120,120,120.0.5) according to the calculation of the max size: Result/maxsize

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? We can't run your query (we don't have access to your instance, nor should we), so unless you tell us the problem. Also, colours are controlled on the presentation layer, not SQL, so not sure why this is a SQL Server question, when it should be controlled on the application.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio doesn't format output the way you describe.  What do you mean by "set the cell's colour according to its value"?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm guessing you are setting the cell color in some sort of visualization tool like PowerBI or Excel or something. Other users seem to be stuck on this part of your question.

For sanity's sake, I'm going to assume you will put the result of the query that builds your data into either a table or temp table. In my example, I'm using a temp table, #data.

```
SELECT MAX(maxdata) FROM (
  SELECT MAX([00:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([01:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([02:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([03:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([04:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([05:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([06:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([07:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([08:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([09:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([10:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([11:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([12:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([13:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([14:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([15:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([16:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([17:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([18:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([19:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([20:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([21:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([22:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX([23:00]) AS maxdata FROM #data
) md
```